# Is there any way to a script inside stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

I know it's a weird scenario. But I need to execute a script inside a stored procedure in SQL Server.

I've created a SQL script to create a test table and populate it with some of the data from the original table. This script is in a separate file.

I also updated some stored procedures to use test mode. I created a parameter called `@IsTestMode` in the stored procedures.

If `@IsTestMode` is true, it checks whether the test table exists or not. If the test table does not exist, It should run that SQL script to create the test table and populate it with the data from the original table.

Is it possible to execute SQL script (in a separate file) inside a stored procedure?

Comment: *Technically* yes, but is it a good idea? Definitely not. This most certainly feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: It's an SQL script? Copy/paste the contents of the script into the procedure :/

Comment: Maybe it's kind of access rights problem ? In that case, use sockets /pipes/ file flag/whatever to signal a scheduler that will launch the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing the script in a file, create a new stored procedure using that code, say `dbo.CreateTestData`. Then, in your main proc:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.Whatever
@IsTestMode BIT = 0 /*Default to no*/
AS
BEGIN
IF @IsTestMode = 1
EXEC dbo.CreateTestData;

DoOtherStuff...
END
GO
```

Comment: Did that exactly. Thanks for the response.